# Error cs0029 cannot implicitly convert type int to bool

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(gemPrefab,new 
isMatched = true;

for (int i = 0; rows.Count; i++) 
{
    rows[i].isMatched = true;
}

if (columns.Count >= AmountToMatch)
{
    isMatched = true;
}

for(int i = 0; columns.Count; i++)
```

However I get the following error:

> Error cs0029 cannot implicitly convert type int to bool (107,25) and (115,25)

How can I fix this?

Comment: cs2009 appears to be a C# error message, which makes sense since if this were C++, it *should* compile but would still be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Your conditions in the `for(...)` expressions need to be boolean expressions.

So rather than `rows.Count`, what you do actually mean? Probably `i < rows.Count`.

The same goes for the expression on line 115. You want `i < columns.Count`.